# Using IPV6 with Dante

Tags: proxy, ipv6, dante

I have a server with one ipv4 ip and plenty of ipv6 ips.

i would like to setup Dante to work as a socks proxy server in my server.

I need to assign different port to each ipv6 port.

Now i can use ipv4 without a problem and when i connect with my server and check my ip it successfully show my ipv4 ip.

I didn't wanna show  my ipv4 to the rest of the world, but only my ipv6 ip .

And also assign different ports to different ipv6 ips , which mean:

```
192.168.1.10:1111 work with ipv6 ip number 1
192.168.1.10:2222 work with ipv6 ip number 2
192.168.1.10:3333 work with ipv6 ip number 2
...........................
etc
```

How can i do this with Dante?

Thanks

Comment: The problem with your requirement *"no IPv4 to the rest of the world"* is that the rest of the world for all practical purposes is still mostly IPv4...

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make my self clear. i mean one we go to some ip detector webiste it show the server ipv6 ip not the real server ipv4 ip. I will access the server through ipv4 IP and outbound with ipv6 IP.

Comment: @HBruijn where in the world are you still finding ipv4, I see a lot of 6 and 4 but I'm not sure where you'd get a v4 only ISP

Comment: ServerFault.com is far from the only site that only advertises an IPv4 `A` record and does not (yet) use IPv6 `AAAA` records , regardless of whether or not their connectivity provider offers IPv6.

Comment: You can get to v4 sites from IPv6.   From what I can tell most carrier traffic is now v6 that was address family translated (from what the carriers in the EU and Americas tell me).  I agree that there is still alot of v4 alive and well, but its by choice not by necessity (which is what it sounded like you were saying)

Answer (score 0):

No, you would need a NAT64 (or some other) address family translator.  Tayga http://www.litech.org/tayga/ would be an example of one.

Comment: Is there any other way that is easy enough to do this. Is there any other socks server script that i can use that support ipv6 as an outbound connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HAproxy if you only need TCP. Set up the IPv6 addresses as backends and listen on different ports on IPv4 as front ends.